# Duplicate of string in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I faced a little trouble. I just wrote a simple shell script to show a few dependencies of maven in files. It works fine. But the only problem. During the process, I show an information about this process progress and so on (I described that in the example below). And one of the lines I display using `printf` is duplicating and it looks like:

> Writing dependencies in ../path/all_dependencies.txt
>
> -- Applying with "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose ".....
>
> -- Applying with "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.servlet".....

I can't get why an additional line appears here. I revealed a lot of sources on the Internet but found nothing in which direction I have to dig. I guess it can be influenced by progress bar but can't understand how exactly.

And what is also interesting, why I get different lines? Maybe it's a feature how arrays work?...

I would appreciate any help/explanation/etc.

This is my script, I added comment before troubled line:

```
#!/bin/sh
start=$(date)
printf "\n Show dependencies from all projects \n $start"
printf "\n -----------------------------------"

#Paths to catalogs
PATH1=..some/path1
PATH2=..some/path2
PATH3=..some/path3

green='\033[0;32m'
red='\033[0;31'
nc='\033[0m'

#  mvn_params represents Maven Parametrs options
#  you can specify here all params you want to use when dependency tree will be applied
#
# E.G: -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.servlet
#
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    maven_params=""
else
    maven_params=( "$@" )
fi

array=(
    $PATH1
    $PATH2
    $PATH3
    )

cp /dev/null all-dependencies.txt

for element in ${array[@]}; do
    module=$element
    if [ -d "$module" ]; then
        cd $element
        full_path="dependencies.txt"
        printf "\n Writing dependencies in $module/$full_path"
        #  A duplicated line is below           
        printf "\n  -- Applying with \"mvn dependency:tree %s \"....." "${maven_params[@]}"

        sp='/-\|'
        printf ' '
        mvn dependency:tree "${maven_params[@]}" > $full_path &
        while [[ -n $(jobs -r) ]]; do
            printf '\b%.1s' "$sp"
            sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}
        done

        status_maven=$?
        cat $full_path >> ../all-dependencies.txt 
        if [ $status_maven -eq 0 ]; then
            printf "\b%.1s ${green}\\u2714${nc} Done\n"
        else
            printf "\b%.1s ${red}\\u274C${nc} Failed\n"
        fi
    else
        printf "\n ${red}\\u274C Failed. ${nc} $module: No such file or directory\n"
    fi
    
done
printf "\n ${green}DONE:${nc} File with all dependencies has been created: all-dependencies.txt"
exit 0
```

Comment: Please clarify first of all which shell you are using. You have tagged your posting as *shell*, which suggests Posix-Shell, and your *#!* line also points towards Posix-Shell, but you are creating an array, and this would not work in Posix-Shell, but in bash, Zsh or ksh.

Comment: @user1934428 actually, it's bash. I'm using "git bash" on Windows.

Comment: Just use `maven_params=()` unconditionally; if `$#` is 0, then `maven_params=()`, which is even *better* than `maven_params=""`, since `"${maven_params[@]}"` will then simply disappear, rather than expand to the empty string and be passed to `mvn` as a distinct argument. Run your code through shellcheck.net; you have a *lot* of small things to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user1934428 I was able to think about array elements representation in a shell. I found a simple solution.
I hope it can be helpful for somebody who will also be looking for an answer.

## SOLUTION:

In my case, I wrote `"${maven_params[@]}"` where `[@]` represents all arguments separated from each other. I had to use `[*]` instead. It provides using array elements in a row like `$1$2`..etc.

> "$@" expands each element as a separate argument, while "$*" expands to the args merged into one argument

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you see, can be demonstrated by this example:

```
printf "\nParameter: %s\n" a b c
```

If you have only one formatting code (here: `%s`), but pass several arguments to `printf`, the string will be used over and over again, so the output of this statement is:

```
Parameter: a

Parameter: b

Parameter: c
```

In your case, it means that the array `maven_params` contains two elements.

Comment: Oh, if I have a few elements in my array then printf will be applied two times in a row... Actually, how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: I found a solution. I had to change in `print` `$@` on `$*`.

Comment: With `"$*"` you make it one argument, while `"$@"` makes it separate arguments. How often printf uses the format, depends of course not only on the number of arguments, but also on the number of `%s` you have in the format.